# Android handle continuous tapping on buttons

Tags: android, button, click

May be it is a question that needs some logic only.

We have an android app that invokes different web services and return data. In the app there are two buttons. We have 10 APIs (web services). Button 1 will invoke the apis api1, api 2 api 3 and api n. Button 2 will invoke api10, api9, api 8… api 1. I am invoking the APIs in the button click but using following code

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        switchToApi(true);
    }
}, 100);
```

As of now the implementation  is in each click its is invoking the APIs. That is if I tapped in button1 it will invoke the api1 and I can only perform other operations after the api1 is completed. But I want, user can continuously tap on the buttons. Continues tap need not invoke the API. But the api number can be changed. That is if a user tapas and wait 2 seconds without taping, then the corresponding APIs should be called. Can you suggest and mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the code below:

```
public static void ButtonLockThread(final int id, final Activity activity) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            activity.findViewById(id).setClickable(true);
        }

    });
    thread.start();

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.armDsarmButton:
        findViewById(R.id.armDsarmButton).setClickable(false);
        WebServiceController.getArmDisarmRelayInfo(this, defaultPanelID);
        Calculations.ButtonLockThread(R.id.armDsarmButton, this);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```